# How to use SiftDescriptorExtractor in openCV 3.0.0

Tags: sift, opencv3.0

I  use SiftDescriptorExtractor in such use :

```
SiftDescriptorExtractor detector;
```

and i try all type bellow:

```
#include <opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp>
#include <features2d.hpp>     
#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d.hpp>
```

but non of them work properly.
anyone know right way to use SiftDescriptorExtractor in openCV 3.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

The standard OpenCV 3.0 builds do no have SIFT included. You need to build and install the contrib module to use SIFT. See [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib). Please take notice of the licensing terms of the SIFT algorithm.